# Parse custom date format using JSON.Net

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm receiving a JSON date in the [following format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time):

```
"launch_date": 1250553600
```

How should I modify the following to include a custom DateTime parser that allows me to convert that number into a `DateTime` object?

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NTask>(json);

public sealed class NTask
{
    public DateTime launch_date { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively I could use `long` and then parse it in another field but I'd rather avoid doing that, and have `JsonConvert` automatically parse it to DateTime through some converter.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackapps.com/questions/1175/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-net-datetime

Comment: See this question asked 19 hours ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639315/how-to-create-a-json-net-date-to-string-custom-converter/8639415#8639415

Comment: @Babcock great link, thank you! If you want to post it as an answer I'll select it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to want to use a [JSONConverter](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute.htm) to help manage the translation. See [this stackapps answer](https://stackapps.com/a/1176) for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code to do that:

```
// This is an example of a UNIX timestamp for the date/time 11-04-2005 09:25.    
double timestamp = 1113211532;

// First make a System.DateTime equivalent to the UNIX Epoch.    
System.DateTime dateTime = new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

// Add the number of seconds in UNIX timestamp to be converted.    
dateTime = dateTime.AddSeconds(timestamp);
```

For your code:

```
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NTask>(json);  

    public sealed class NTask
    {
        public DateTime launch_date { get; set; }

        public void SetLaunchDate(int timestamp)
        {
            // First make a System.DateTime equivalent to the UNIX Epoch.    
            var dateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

            // Add the number of seconds in UNIX timestamp to be converted.    
            launch_date = dateTime.AddSeconds(timestamp);
        }
    }
```

Then when you are Deserializing the JSON, check to see if the `launch_date` is of type `int` or `DateTime` and switch how you set the object based on the type!