# ASP.NET Web API Date format in JSON does not serialise successfully

Tags: c#, serialization, asp.net-web-api, json.net

All,

We are using ASP.NET Web API where we have a REST based service with JSON for the payload. If I pass the following Date as a string e.g

```
sampleObj: {
...
myDate: "31/12/2011 00:00:00",
...
}
```

as an attribute value in the JSON payload, the date attribute gets deserialised into a DateTime.MinValue. Is the string format valid?

We know the format "2012-10-17 07:45:00" serialises successfully but we cannot guarantee that all dates received will be in this format. What are the valid options?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In ASP.NET Web API, you can add different Json.NET DateTimeConverters through the JsonFormatter's SerializerSettings to make your service understand different DateTime format.

However, I do not think there is a default DateTimeConverter from Json.NET that takes in this format "31/12/2011 00:00:00".  In this case you implement your custom DateTimeConverter.

WebApiConfig.cs:

```
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(
             new IsoDateTimeConverter());
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(
             new MyDateTimeConverter());
```

Custom DateTimeConverter:

```
public class MyDateTimeConverter : DateTimeConverterBase
{
    //...
}
```

For more information about how to write a custom DateTimeConverter, I found something on stackoverflow that you might find useful:
[How to create a json.net Date to String custom Converter.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639315/how-to-create-a-json-net-date-to-string-custom-converter)

Comment: Thanks for that help. We will not be creating a custom date time converter, I just wanted to confirm that the format was not acceptable by Json.NET by default.

Answer (score 4):

Just set globalization in web.config:

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="false" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB"/>
```

and then, in Global.asax.cs > Application_Start, set JsonFormatter to use the current culture:

```
var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.Culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
```