# Web API DateTime not being parsed

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am receiving POST data from a vendor's web service in my web api. One of the values being sent is a data and time - sample: `StartTime=2014-10-20+15%3A30%3A54`. I understand that `%3A` is an escape for `:`, which would have a date in the following format: `2014-10-20+15:30:54`.

The problem is that the `StartTime` value is not being parsed properly by the web api, and all the `StartDate` properties on my model are being set to `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? I can't seem to find any info on what format this date is in to see if there is a way to have the web api framework parse it correctly.

Comment: I had this before Web API expects date time in the form of       MM-dd-yyyy. You can try formatting it this way ...

Comment: The problem is that I am getting the information passed from a 3rd party. I do not have any control over the format of the date they are passing.

Comment: Can you do `var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>` where <T>  is your response object ?

Comment: JSON.NET supports custom DateTime converters. You can take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936614/asp-net-web-api-date-format-in-json-does-not-serialise-successfully

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Request Body:

```
{"StartTime":"2014-10-20+15:30:54"}
```

Parse:

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string format = "yyyy-MM-dd+HH:mm:ss";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(request.StartTime, format, provider);
```