# custom conversion from T to a MultilingualValue<T> in JSON.Net

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a lot of entities which previously used to have properties of type for example `string`.  I need to change these to a custom type - `MultilingualValue<T>`, where T in this case would be `string`.  I can easily convert from `string` to the custom Type.  Is it possible to configure JSON.Net such that everywhere it encounters a conversion from any type, to a `MultilingualValue<T>`, some custom code is called rather than it's native conversion?

Sample code

```
public class ProductBefore
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ProductAfter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public MultilingualValue<string> Name { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to be able to deserialize anything which was stored as `ProductBefore`, into `ProductAfter` automatically.  The `MultilingualValue<string>` can be initialised with a `string` parameter in the constructor, so it's relatively easy to create it from the original `string`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a json.net Date to String custom Converter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639315/how-to-create-a-json-net-date-to-string-custom-converter)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth This is unrelated - I want to set this 'globally', as I am not using Json.Net directly but as part of `RavenDB`. I would like to set it such that whenever it encounters a conversion from `T` -> `MultilingualValue<T>`, some custom converter is called

Comment: And how are we supposed to know this when you don't add that to your question?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I think I have already explained in the question what I required, but if you think it needs any further clarifications let me know.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Managed to do it via the `Converters`.  Posting as answer just in case it might be of help to anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible through adding a Custom `Converter`.  These can be added as per below:

```
    private void createJsonSerializer()
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings settingsSerialize = new JsonSerializerSettings();

        settingsSerialize.Converters.Add(CustomConverter.Instance);

        _jsonSeriazlier = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Create(settingsSerialize);

    }
```

Just in case it is of help to anyone, below is the custom converter itself:

```
    public class CustomConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public CustomConverter()
        {


        }
        public override bool CanWrite
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        private static readonly CustomConverter _instance = new CustomConverter();

        public static CustomConverter Instance
        {
            get { return _instance; }
        }
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {

            return (objectType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(MultilingualValue<MultilingualValueMetaData<string>>)));

        }

           public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
           {
               MultilingualValue<MultilingualValueMetaData<string>> result = new MultilingualValue<MultilingualValueMetaData<string>>();
               JsonToken firstToken = reader.TokenType;
               reader.Read();//skip first Token
               while (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndObject)
               {
                   string languageType = (string) reader.Value;
                   reader.Read();
                   MultilingualValueMetaData<string> metaData = null;
                   if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
                   {
                       metaData = serializer.Deserialize<MultilingualValueMetaData<string>>(reader);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       metaData = new MultilingualValueMetaData<string>();
                       metaData.AutoTranslation = (string) reader.Value;


                   }
                   result[languageType] = metaData;
                   reader.Read();
               }
               return result;


           }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {



        }
    }
```