# How to set globalization?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, globalization

I'm stuck in an ASP.NET Web API Globalization problem. I want to get date time in culture specific format when I invoke a Web API. Please provide some insights.

In my solution, first, there is one delegating handler, whose job is to set the culture. It is defined as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

namespace CultureHandling.Handlers
{
     public class CultureHandler : DelegatingHandler
     {
          protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, 
               CancellationToken cancellationToken)
          {
                  if (request != null && request.Headers != null && request.Headers.Count() > 0)
                  {
                        var reqHdrs = request.Headers.AcceptLanguage;
                        var headerValue = reqHdrs.OrderByDescending(e => e.Quality ?? 1.0D)
                                .Where(e => !e.Quality.HasValue || e.Quality.Value > 0.0D)
                                .First();


                       System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = 
                       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(headerValue.Value.ToString());
                       System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
                       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(headerValue.Value.ToString());
                    }
                    return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
                 }
             }
        }
   }
```

Then, I have a date time converter defined as:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

namespace CultureHandling.Converters
{
    public class CustomDateTimeConverter : DateTimeConverterBase
    {
        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            return (DateTime.Parse(reader.Value.ToString()));
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            writer.WriteValue(((DateTime)value).ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The very simple model class is:

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Doj { get; set; }
    }
```

And the corresponding controller action is:

```
    public class EmployeeController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly List<Employee> employees = null;
        public EmployeeController()
        {
            employees = new List<Employee>();
            employees.Add(new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "Employee1", Doj = new DateTime(2014, 7, 1)});
            employees.Add(new Employee { Id = 2, Name = "Employee2", Doj = new DateTime(2015, 7, 1)});
        }

        public List<Employee> Get()
        {
            return employees;
        }
    }
```

I've configured the WebApiConfig.cs as:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new CultureHandler());
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new CustomDateTimeConverter());
```

Now, the problem part:
Ideally if I invoke the API with Accept Language as *en-US*, it should return date time value is **MM/dd/yyyy** format and for *fr-FR*, the format is **dd/MM/yyyy**. But, for both of these cases, I'm getting value in MM/dd/yyyy format.

As per investigation, I found the CultureHandler to be working as expected, here is a screenshot of Postman:

[image]

The break-point in CultureHandler.cs:
[image]

But, surprisingly, during model binding, I'm seeing the culture to be changed to en-US:

[image]

I believe this is the reason why I'm not getting date time value in **dd/MM/yyyy** format when culture is fr-FR:

[image]

So, my question is why and where does this culture getting changed? Am I making any mistake in coding? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using Windows 10 system. System date time format:MM/dd/yyyy.
Project is in .NET Framework 4.6.

Comment: It is because you are using async Tasks. Task scheduler selects any free thread to continue the task execution. Just because you set current culture for one thread, it doesn't mean it stays the same for another.

Comment: @TomasŠvedas: I've found localization of resource (sending french message text from Resources.fr-fr.resx) to be working in this way! Anyways, how should I handle the date time formatting then?

Comment: check this as it might help https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/06/22/request-culture-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 0):

I create a new empty project then i wrote all shared code in my solution. Your code is work true. Screenshots is below

[image: en]

[image: fr]

I tried with postman.