# How to setup multilingual and localized Views in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

i already have one MVC website in english language. Now I need to add arabic language. To do that i want to use structure below to store my localized .cshtml files

**English Views**
~/Views/index.cshtml
~/Views/about.cshtml

**Arabic Views**

~/ar/Views/index.cshtml

~/ar/Views/about.cshtml

**English URL (It's working)**

[www.samplesite.com/home/index](http://www.samplesite.com/home/index)

[www.samplesite.com/home/index](http://www.samplesite.com/home/index)

**Arabic URL (It's not working)**

[www.samplesite.com/ar/home/index](http://www.samplesite.com/ar/home/index)

[www.samplesite.com/ar/home/index](http://www.samplesite.com/ar/home/index)

I need to return english view if url with /en or no language parameter and if URL starts with /ar i need to return view in ar/Views folder. What should i change in route config and actions to get the correct view based on URL ?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In order to localize the ASP.NET MVC app with different views for different languages and cultures, you need to at least do:

1. Save language code from URL to route data collection, if exists
2. Set current culture based on the language code, if exists
3. Route the request to localized views, if language code appears

### 1. Save language code from URL to route data collection, if exists

You need to define the route mapping so that whenever there is a language code on the URL, it would be put to the route data collection.

You can define the extra route mapping in the `RouteConfig`:

```cs
namespace DL.SO.Globalization.DotNet.Web.UI
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.LowercaseUrls = true;

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DefaultWithLang",
                url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                constraints: new { lang = new LanguageRouteConstraint() }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

We will come back to the route constraint, but the idea here is to run this "DefaultWithLang" mapping first, and see if the incoming request has the language code attached on it or not. If yes, save it to the route collection with the key `lang`. Otherwise, just process it as normal.

#### Route constraints

Imagine we have those 2 mappings defined, and the incoming request looks like `/home/index`. Without that route constraint, this would be mapped to the "DefaultWithLang" with `lang` being "home", which is incorrect.

We will need a way to test whether the language code is a valid 2-letter code. To do that, you can create a route constraint:

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace DL.SO.Globalization.DotNet.Web.UI.RouteConstraints
{
    public class LanguageRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
    {
        public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, 
            RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
            return Regex.IsMatch((string)values[parameterName], @"^[a-z]{2}$");
        }
    }
}
```

With this in placed, the request "/home/index" will first come in with "home" being the language code, but it will fail this route constraint because it has more than 2 letters. This would result no matching for "DefaultWithLang" map. Then the MVC will continue to use the 2nd mapping and see if the request is a valid request, which it is!

### 2. Set current culture based on the language code, if exists

Now we know the language code will be put into the route data collection. We can set the current culture and the current UI culture of the current thread based on that.

To do so, we can create an `ActionFilter`:

```cs
namespace DL.SO.Globalization.DotNet.Web.UI.Filters
{
    public class LanguageFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            var values = filterContext.RouteData.Values;

            string languageCode = (string)values["lang"] ?? "en";

            var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(languageCode);

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureInfo.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Here I am reading the language code value from the route data collection, or it defaults to "en" if it doesn't exist.

To enable it for the whole application, you can add it to `FilterConfig.cs`:

```cs
namespace DL.SO.Globalization.DotNet.Web.UI
{
    public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new LanguageFilter());
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }
    }
}
```

### 3. Route the request to localized views, if language code appears

Similar to Step #2, now we have the language code, we need to create a custom view engine to route the request to different views:

```cs
namespace DL.SO.Globalization.DotNet.Web.UI
{
    public class GlobalizationRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
    {
        protected override IView CreatePartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
            string partialPath)
        {
            partialPath = GetGlobalizeViewPath(controllerContext, partialPath);
            return base.CreatePartialView(controllerContext, partialPath);
        }

        protected override IView CreateView(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
            string viewPath, string masterPath)
        {
            viewPath = GetGlobalizeViewPath(controllerContext, viewPath);
            return base.CreateView(controllerContext, viewPath, masterPath);
        }

        private string GetGlobalizeViewPath(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
            string viewPath)
        {
            var request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
            var values = controllerContext.RouteData.Values;

            string languageCode = (string)values["lang"];
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(languageCode))
            {
                string localizedViewPath = Regex.Replace(viewPath,
                    "^~/Views/",
                    String.Format("~/{0}/Views/", languageCode)
                );

                if (File.Exists(request.MapPath(localizedViewPath)))
                {
                    viewPath = localizedViewPath;
                }
            }

            return viewPath;
        }
    }
}
```

The logic here should be straight forward: if the language code exists, try to append it to the original view path the MVC app was going to use to find the corresponding view.

**Note**: you would need to copy `_viewStart.cshtml` as well as `web.config` from the original `Views` folder to the new localized `Views` folder. You might consider using different folder structure to contain all localized views. One possible way is to put them all inside the `~/Views` folder.

To use this custom view engine, you would need to add it to the view engine collection at `Application_Start()`:

```cs
namespace DL.SO.Globalization.DotNet.Web.UI
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
            ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new GlobalizationRazorViewEngine());

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```

### Screenshots

[image]

With `zh/` on the URL:

[image]

The folder structure:

[image]

**Github source code:** https://github.com/davidliang2008/DL.SO.Globalization.DotNet/tree/master/DL.SO.Globalization.DotNet.Web.UI

Comment: What is the point of step 2 (setting current culture)? You are capturing the culture info in route data (step 1) and using that in step 3 to change the view selection logic based on culture.

Comment: @SkShahnawaz-ulHaque: Setting the culture and UI culture is needed to display numbers and dates correctly in the application. Now if you have static numbers and dates in any of those localized views, you don't need that. But if the data is coming from the database, you actually need to set the cultures in order to display them correctly.

Comment: If that is the case, could you help me with this? It is also globalization, but in Web API:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60648268/how-to-set-globalization